# Pass several 'Name, Value' parameters to a MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, function, parameters

I am trying to figure out how I can pass several optional 'Name','Value' pair parameters to a MATLAB function like this: https://es.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcknn.html

I mean, my parameters are stored in a struct, but this struct does not always contain the same number of parameters pair. E.g., I can have the following struct:

```
options.NumNeighbors = 3
options.Standardize = 1;
```

So, the function calling would be:

```
output = fitcknn(X,Y,'NumNeighbors',options.NumNeighbors,'Standardize',options.Standardize);
```

But, another time I could have:

```
options.NumNeighbors = 3
options.Standardize = 1;
options.ScoreTransform = 'logit';
```

And thus, the function calling will have another parameter pair:

```
output = fitcknn(X,Y,'NumNeighbors',options.NumNeighbors,'Standardize',...
options.Standardize,'ScoreTransform',options.ScoreTransform);
```

What I want is to dynamically call the function without worrying about the final number of pair 'Name'-'Value' parameters. I have tested something like this, but it does not work:

```
options = {'NumNeighbors',3,'Standardize',1};
output = fitcknn(X,Y,options);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a [comma-separated](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) list as input.
So just add a {:} to your option input.

```
options = {'NumNeighbors',3,'Standardize',1};
output = fitcknn(X, Y, options{:});
```

The options input could be generated from the struct by a simple `for`loop.

(In the example below I'm using `listdlg` instead of `fitcknn` as I currently could not obtain the toolbox)

```
options.ListString = {'a','b'};
options.Name = 'Test';
options.ListSize = [200 300];

optInput = {};
for optField = fieldnames(options)'
    optInput{end+1} = char(optField);
    optInput{end+1} = options.(char(optField));
end
listdlg(optInput{:})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `varargin` function in your function declaration. It collects all extra inputs into a cell array that you can parse inside your function.

Your function declaration will look like this:

```
function [out]=myfunc(in1,in2,varargin)
% in1 and in2 are mandatory inputs
```

and you would call your function like this:

```
[out]=myfunc(in1,in2,optionalIn1,optionalIn2,...,optionalInN)
```

You would then get a cell array `varargin` in your function's workspace where:

```
varargin{1}=optionalIn1;
varargin{2}=optionalIn2;
...
varargin{N}=optionalInN;
```

You can then parse this to suit your needs.

Comment: This answer does not answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood the question, I assumed the person asking the question would know about `{:}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following  way:

```
options = {'NumNeighbors',3,'Standardize',1};
output = fitcknn(X,Y,options{:});
```